# Initialization, conditions, and afterthought of for-looping to add variable value each time the arraylist size reach certain value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to make a program that consist of 1 arraylist and 1 variable. So, every time the arraylist's size 59, 118, 177,..... (added by 59), will add the variable by 1.

```
int a = 0;
ArrayList<String> arrayLog = new ArrayList<>();

androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton log = findViewById(R.id.log);
log.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    arrayLog.add("Clicked");
}

int n = arrayLog.size();
```

I don't know what I should write for the next part but it should be like this:

If n = 59, a = 1

If n = 59+59 = 118, a = 2

If n = 59+59+59 = 177, a = 3

I'm thinking about using for loop, but I don't know what I should write for the initialization, condition and afterthought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide `n` with 59, round it down and assign it to `a`:

```
a = (n / 59);
```

Comment: If n = 0 then a = ??  And if n = 1 then a =0.016?

Comment: n is the size of array. it starts from 0 till the end of user input or click the button. so if the user clicked the button for 5 times, n = 5.

Comment: @Abisay "_If n = 0 then a = ??_" -- `a = 0` in that case. "_And if n = 1 then a =0.016?_" -- No, `a = 0` in this case as well. Both `n` and `59` are `int`s, so integer division is being used (plus the answer [unnecessarily] casts to `int`, so any fractional part would have been dropped even if true division was being used).

Comment: I got confused by this. I tried the integer division with int 0 divided by integer 5 and the output is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: @Slaw point taken, thanks. Removed the unnecessary cast.

Comment: @Abisay If n = 0, then a should be 0. If n = 1 then a should be 0. If n = 59, then a should be 1. The error you have mentioned can only happen if you divided by zero instead of dividing zero by the value you wanted to divide it with.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes it works. I messed up with the variables. I forgot that int won't keep decimals like float.

Comment: @Abisay happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Is it right if I make it like this?

```
int a = 0;
ArrayList<String> arrayLog = new ArrayList<>();

androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton log = findViewById(R.id.log);
log.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    arrayLog.add("Clicked");

}

int n = arrayLog.size();

if(n % 59 == 0){
    a++;
}
```

If this right, then it means it doesn't have to use for-loop.

Comment: You don't need to use a `for` loop for this purpose. But `n % 59 == 0` is incorrect as a formula, because it's true for 0, 59, 118, etc. You need to find out how many times there is 59 in n, that is, division rather than remainder.

Comment: @LajosArpad I don't need to know how many times there is 59 in n. What I need is to add a by 1 every time n = multiple of 59. When n = 59,  a(0)+1=1 . Then when n=118, a(1)+1 = 2.

Comment: But it so happens that the results coincide. Think again :)

Comment: @LajosArpad Well it works well cause every time n % 59 == 0, a will be +1. Well I know if I don't use prime numbers like 59, the results may different. But as long it's in prime number, it works well.

Comment: One point is that `n / 59` will always give you the correct, most up-to-date answer for the current value of `n`. Whereas doing `if (n % 59 == 0) a++;` requires you remember to do that whenever `n` increments; and what happens if `n` increases by more than `1` at a time, or even decreases?

Comment: @Slaw in this case, how could n increases more than 1 or decreases?

Comment: @Abisay From the little bit of code you've provided? It can't. I'm only thinking toward the future, and how refactoring could break things. I'm of the opinion that `n / 59` is more maintainable. That doesn't mean you have to use it. Just wanted to point out an advantage I see in using `n / 59`.